# Importing from Excel to multivalued field in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, import, ms-access-2013, import-from-excel

I have Multi value field in `TaskTbl` named `EmployeeID`.
I have around 800 tasks in Excel file, where the Data is like below

```
TaskID | Task | EmployeeID

1      |aa    | 1,4

2      |ab    | 2,3

3      |ac    | 1,2
```

Tried to import the data using Excel Import,in Access 2013, but I get error.
But, if I insert the value manually in access and export the data to Excel, the data is in exactly the same format. Where am going Wrong?

I searched here, also on some other forms, I got the answer in a old Question of Year 2008 that, in Office 2007, you cannot import a Multivalue Field.

I was wondering if, there is a way to import without using VBA, as I am not well versed with VBA.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are importing it. Since you have a comma in the value, you are going to have to import it as a string/text. This is going to present problems when you are trying to figure out what Employee is responsible for what task.

Do you ever have more than 2 Employees in the task?

My guess is that you're trying track whose responsible for a given task.

Your database design would be better if you had a table of assigned tasks which tracks the task ID and the EmployeeID.

This would be a 1:Many relationship between tasks and your assigned to table

For example,
`tblAssignedTasks
[AssignedTaskID], [TaskID], [EmployeeID]
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 4
3, 2, 2
4, 2, 3
5, 3, 1
5, 3, 2`

Depending on how your source data is setup, this is going to take a little work to get into the proper database format. You first have to separate out your values, and then get them columns into rows.

This formula will extract the first employee:
`=LEFT(C2,FIND(",",C2)-1)`

This formula will extract the second employee:
`=MID(C2,FIND(",",C2)+1,LEN(C2))`

If you have more than two, it will be a different design.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping, a way to directly import, will give your method a try.